# Could not load file or assembly on server for non referenced library

Tags: iis, umbraco, .net-assembly

On our dev server, in (MVC only I think) we are getting an error

*Could not load file or assembly 'Umbraco.Forms.CodeFirst' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

The unexpected things us we are suddenly getting this error in applications that dont even use Umbraco. The app code has not been updated.

I've trued moving a broken application to a new app pool in IIS but no luck.

We thought it may be due to an issue with Global assembly cache but I can't see Umbraco dlls there.

The only thing I can think may have caused it is when I converted a virtual directory for an Umbraco web site to an Application. But I've since removed it, and we are still seeing issues with the none Umbraco sites. I dont understand how the change to the Umbraco web site can affect the other sites...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it all apps on the dev server or just some? A few things to check ... Are the affected apps running as virtual directories under an Umbraco install? Has the machine config been amended to contain Umbraco references? Are the any global IIS settings/Umbraco modules?

Answer (score 0):

The assembly mentioned is related to a commercial product called Umbraco Contour. Make sure there are no references in your Web.Config and that none of your projects are holding any reference to the assemblies.

Comment: This is across multiple sites without a reference to Umbraco. Like I say, there hasnt been any code changes so it's a config issue. We do use Umbraco for some projects but it's not clear how this is affecting other web sites ...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it was that somehow the web.config for another project somehow got deposited in the root directory for iis and was affecting all sites. Doh!